# emf inter modeling referenses

Tags: eclipse, modeling, emf, xmi, ecore

I'm working on EMF on eclipse modeling tools, mars.1 .

I have to .ecore metamodel files , let's say A.ecore and B.ecore. By using the "right  click -> load Resource -> worskpace "  method , i added a reference from a class of A to a class of B  (A!Class1.ref = B!class2). What i want now is to create 2 DYNAMIC instances let's say instA.xmi and instB.xmi , and reference a B!Class2 element to a A!Class1 element.

I right clicked in my root element of B and creates the instB.xmi. I then do the same for instA.xmi , i load the isntB.xmi resource from the worskspace, but when i try to assign a value to my reference , the combo is always empty. If i manually (via text editor) add this reference, it results on an error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the `A.ecore` URI and the `B.ecore` URI are different? The only way I have to reproduce your issue is to set the same URI for `A.ecore` and `B.ecore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry , it was a mistake with the URIs. Because i was working on a plugin project and i had some mixed "platform:/plugin" and "platform:/resource" across all models and metamodels , it took me a while to notice.